# How do I correct an "the security database on the server does not have a computer account" on a domain controller?

Tags: domain-controller, login

I have taken over the management of several machines and domain at the place I work and think I have a corrupted domain "database" for lack of a better term.

When I try and log into the domain controller I get the error:

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account
>   for this workstation trust relationship.

All searching on this topic seems to relate to rejoining workstations to domains or spn data being wrong. I have tried to correct the SPN details but that didn't fix the issue. I'm not sure how I would go about rejoining a domain controller to a domain, it's not a viable fix for a dc in my books.

Any thoughts?

Also, another things I can login to this domain controller at the console in the first 15 seconds after reboot but if I wait any longer then I get the same message at the console.

At the moment I am using MMCs to manage the server remotely which works but I would like to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something's seriously messed up with that DC - if possible, consider just rebuilding it.

Also check for the same basics that you'd check for another system with this issue - that it has working name resolution, that its name matches its computer account in the domain, and that it and the other domain controllers have correct time.  And `dcdiag` is always worth a look.

Anyway, what you'd want to try for rebuilding the trust with the domain will be the procedure outlined [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325850) - stop the KDC service then run a `netdom resetpwd` against the DC to rebuild its computer account.

Comment: Heh, I know ... I'll end up rebuilding as I just don't trust it. Thanks for the other suggestions, I'll give the 'netdom resetpwd' a go.